# Pandas: Groupby a certain name in a row and print

Tags: python, pandas

[Table of Data of Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4ReO.png)

```
Name Classes 

John Math 
John English 
John Writing 
Bill Spanish 
Bill Math 
Bill Biology 
Rex English 
Rex Writing 
Rex Geology 
Sam Spanish 
Sam Biology
```

Using pandas, given the following table with a column of names and a column of classes taken, how do you return a variable with all the classes "John" has taken?

Comment: Do not worry about formatting, paste the data here. We dont want images.

Comment: Use Groupby Names then use `get_loc` to get the classes i.e `samp = df.groupby('Name').agg(lambda x : list(x))` then to select the classes attended use `samp.loc['John']`

Answer (score 0):

Pasting the data will make it easier to answer, but anyways you can try this to get a list of classes taken by John

```
df[df['name'] == 'John']['classes'].tolist()
```

Comment: This aint what OP wanted